# Use your bot as a normal user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've seen someone around using their bot to reply inside a server as if the bot was just a normal user, i tried to look for something similar and the only thing i found is this:

https://github.com/ZomoXYZ/Discord-Bot-Client

Which is like having a separate client to use for your bot. I would like to know if we could just skip all that stuff and implement it in our own bot instead of using that as a secondary discord client.

Any suggestion or someone who achieved this and wanna share it or send it privately i'll be thankful.

EDIT: i'm sorry for the confusion but what i'm looking for is not a selfbot it is a way on using your own normal discord bot to be able to text and the example of that discord bot client is fairly what i'm trying to achieve. so let's say you made a new bot and invited it to your server, implementing a code where that bot is able to be used as a normal user-account and not a selfbot when you're using your own account.

Comment: Unfortunately, using what's called "self-bots" or "user-bots" is against Discord's ToS. Read more [here](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots). Basically, you must [create a bot account](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord.html) to run a bot.

Comment: Edited my question because i may have not explained properly

Comment: So.... what do you want this bot todo? `where the bot is able to be used as a normal user-account and not a selfbot` Doesn't explain anything.

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer basically, selfbot is when someone use user account to act like a bot, while what this person want is the opposite, make bot to act like user account

Answer (score 3):

After digging around, I think I have a good answer to your updated question. No, it is not against ToS as far as I have seen. I scrolled through dozens of articles that have said the same thing. It isn't against ToS directly (no, it doesn't fall under the self-bot category), but it is kind of on the edge. They don't say anywhere that you can't do it, and honestly it's not that different from using an eval command to send a message to a channel, except it is easier and looks better. Also there is also no reason as to why they should block it in the future. While with a self bot you can login and spam messages or dm advertise a bunch of members automatically, logging in to a bot account gives you a higher ratelimit for the same features you would get by just joining the server with your normal account. As for permissions, you can't do any more than you could by coding it, and the server admin that invited the bot gave it the permissions that it has. You aren't magically getting more of anything out of using a client such as [Discord-Bot-Client](https://github.com/ZomoXYZ/Discord-Bot-Client) or [LiveBot](https://github.com/SebOuellette/LiveBot). It just gives a better ui experience than using code to do the same thing. Sorry I'm late on this answer but I hope it helps anyone who clicks on this and sees it.

TL;DR: They didn't say its against ToS, and there isn't any reason it should be.

Answer (score 1):

## Note, this no longer works due to Discord.js API updates. I no longer use Discord.js, so I cannot tell you how to make a self bot. However; what lies below may still help you, but no longer is the answer.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

## Self Bots are NOT allowed.

([Link](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots))
Self bot's used to be used and was just ignored by Discord but in the last year they've decided to enforce it. You  may get your account **banned** by doing this. Just make and use a normal bot: https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/

## How todo it anyways.

When you make your bot somewhere you need a `bot.login(<key>)` You just need to find YOUR key to have it run as a selfbot.

Note: this works on both the WEB version & the downloadable app.

### Step 1:

Login into discord, navigate to a TextChannel so you can send a message. Open the CONSOLE by either `CTRL-SHIFT-I` for windows, and I assume but am not sure `CMD-SHIFT-I` for mac.
Head into the **NETWORK** tab. So you should see somthing like:
[image: Metwork Tab]

### Step 2:

Click on the Ø (Circle w/ slash) to easier find what we're going todo next.
[image: Ø (Circle w/ slash)]
After you've cleared the network tab send a messaage into your channel and you should see 2 or more items pop up in the network tab, click on the first one that should say `messages` as it's name.

### Step 3:

When you click on the `messages` item, you should open another tab inside the network tab Click on the HEADERS tab inside the new tab[image: Image pointing toward the headers tab]
After that scroll down until you reach "Request Headers" section. Under that section grab the "Authorization" Value
[image: Image of where the Authorization value is]
That value is what you use in your `bot.login(<key>)`

I can't guarantee this will work, as I haven't tried it recently, but this is what I know from doing it in the past and from what I know from other's expierences.

Comment: Edited my question because i may have not explained properly

Comment: This method won't work on the latest version of Discord.js anyway due to API changes and deprecation.